# Does snowflake has a workload management feature like RedShift?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In AWS Redshift we can manage query priority using WLM. Do we have any such feature for Snowflake or is it done using multi warehouse strategy?

Comment: Yes, you ether use different warehouses, to act as QOS buckets/groups. Or auto-scaling on those warehouses to dynamically handle load growth. And/or manual resizing of warehouses, all-at-the-same-time for complete control/happiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got the right idea that warehouses are typically the best approach this problem in Snowflake.

If you have a high priority query/process/account, it's entirely reasonable to provide that with a dedicated warehouse. That will guarantee that your query won't be competing with any resources on other warehouses.

You can also then size that warehouse appropriately. if it's a Small query, or file copy query, for example, and it's just really important that it runs right away, then you can give it a dedicated Small/X-Small warehouse. If it's a big query that doesn't run very frequently, you can give it a larger warehouse. If you set it to auto-suspend then you won't even incur much extra cost for the extra dedicated compute.